# Modified .bower.json file not updating

Tags: javascript, bower

When I download a package with bower it creates a `.bower.json` file in the package folder. When I modify the ignore list and run `bower update` it does not update however.

```
{
  "name": "less",
  "version": "1.6.3",
  "main": "./dist/less-1.6.3.js",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "test",
    "*.md",
    "LICENSE",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "package.json",
    "bower.json"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/less/less",
  "_release": "1.6.3",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v1.6.3",
    "commit": "0cfd753e3750ff1ee4c54e09d10ea1a633b0ce89"
  },
  "_source": "git://github.com/less/less.git",
  "_target": "1.6.3",
  "_originalSource": "less"
}
```

is changed to

```
{
  "name": "less",
  "version": "1.6.3",
  "main": "./dist/less-1.6.3.js",
  "ignore": [
    "LICENSE",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "package.json",
    "bower.json"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/less/less",
  "_release": "1.6.3",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v1.6.3",
    "commit": "0cfd753e3750ff1ee4c54e09d10ea1a633b0ce89"
  },
  "_source": "git://github.com/less/less.git",
  "_target": "1.6.3",
  "_originalSource": "less"
}
```

Is there any way to get these files in my package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason it's prefixed with a dot and hidden. You're not supposed to touch it. It's for use internally in Bower. If you need to update the ignore list you should submit a pull request to the bower.json of the package in question.

Comment: Seems apropos for semver implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Does Bower recognize a difference if the package folder contains both `.bower.json` and `bower.json` ?  Which is the preferred?