# WebPack: How to look both for bower.json and .bower.json

Tags: node.js, bower, webpack

I have been able to get webpack to look for components inside `bower_components`. I'm running in to issues when a bower component only includes `.bower.json` and not a `bower.json` file (notice that the first filename is preceded by a `.`).

A simplified version of my `webpack.config.js` file looks as follows:

```
var ResolverPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ResolverPlugin');

// webpack configuration
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: 'app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'web_modules', 'bower_components', 'static']
    },
    plugins: [
        new ResolverPlugin(
            new ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin('bower.json', ['main'])
        )
    ]
};
```

I'm trying to use [jquery.selectBoxIt](http://bower.io/search/?q=jquery.selectBoxIt) as a bower component. Another issue might be that its lacking a `main` field in its `.bower.json` file. For what it's worth, I've included that file below:

```
// .bower.json

{
  "name": "jquery.selectBoxIt",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js",
  "version": "3.8.1",
  "_release": "3.8.1",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v3.8.1",
    "commit": "ffa615b25ebf4fac392726b17c857d429acf244c"
  },
  "_source": "git://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js.git",
  "_target": "~3.8.1",
  "_originalSource": "jquery.selectBoxIt",
  "_direct": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.bower.json` is a file generated by Bower during dependency resolution. It is not equivalent to `bower.json` and generally should not be used as it is an [internal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689003/1097634) file which may change.
In cases where you see only a `.bower.json` file it means that the package does not have a `bower.json` (Bower can actually work without it). In such cases it means that you will not be able to find the "main" property.
For example the [jquery.selectBoxIt.js](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js) package has bower.json file only in their master branch but not in their release tags (it was probably not released yet). When you resolve it, Bower will use the 3.8.1 git tag as you can see in the .bower.json file. In this tag there is no bower.json file.
For such packages you may want to consider another option such as CommonsJS.

Comment: So far I have added an additional plugin to my webpack config. This looks at `.bower.json`'s `_originalSource` field. It works, but would you say this is a risky solution? If you think so I'll resort to using CommonJS

Comment: `_originalSource` is not equivalent to the main property so I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use it. In cases where you do not have a bower.json you have no way of knowing what is the main file(s). In such cases I think you should try using another descriptor that contains this information. In addition the structure of the .bower.json file is not public and may change (or may not) in the future.